# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s^2}{s^2+4s+13}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Would you know where I was wrong?

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \dfrac{s^2}{s^2+4s+13}\right] =\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \dfrac{s^2}{(s+2)^2+9}\right] =-\dfrac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \dfrac{s}{(s+2)^2+9}\right] =\dfrac{-de^{-2t}}{ds}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \dfrac{s-2}{s^2+9}\right]\left. \right|_{s\to s+2}=-\dfrac{de^{-2t}}{ds}\left( \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \dfrac{s}{s^2+9}\right] -2\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \dfrac{1}{s^2+9}\right] \right) =\dfrac{-d}{ds}e^{-2t}\left( \cos (3t)-\dfrac23 \sin (3t)\right) =4e^{-2t}\cos (3t)+\dfrac53 e^{-2t}\sin (3t)$$
The solution they give me is:
$$\boxed{g(t)=-4e^{-2t}\cos (3t)-\dfrac53 e^{-2t}\sin (3t)+\delta (t).}$$

Comment: In the second equation, the derivative should be with respect to the variable of the inverse Laplace transform, not the variable $s$ of the transform. When you take derivative of the inverse Laplace, $\mathcal{L}[f'(t)]=s\mathcal{L}[f](s)-\mathcal{L}[f](0^+)$. Since in your case $\mathcal{L}[f](0^+)=0$, then $\mathcal{L}[f'(t)]=s\mathcal{L}[f](s)$. So, there is no minus needed in front.

Comment: The other part in which there is a problem is in the inverse Laplace of $\frac{s}{s^2+9}$ and $\frac{1}{s^2+9}$. These are $\cos(3t)u(t)$ and $\frac{1}{3}\sin(3t)u(t)$, respectively, where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function. You will need to take this factor $u$ into account when you take the $\frac{d}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\dfrac{s^2}{s^2+4s+13} = 1-\dfrac{4s+13}{s^2+4s+13}
$$

NOTE

$$
\dfrac{s^2}{s^2+4s+13} \ \ \ \text{is not strictly causal}
$$